# Метод не возвращает значение

Tags: c++, классы, динамические-массивы

```
        class Setr
                {
                private:
                    int *ptr; // указатель на массив
                    int size; // размер массива
                public:
                    Setr();
                    Setr(int );
                    Setr(const Setr &);
                    ~Setr();
                    void setSetr();
                    void getSetr();
                    int &operator[] (int);
                    Setr &operator+= (const int &);
                    Setr &operator-= (const int &);
                    Setr operator+ (Setr &);
                    Setr operator* (Setr &);
                    Setr operator/ (Setr &);
                };    



        Setr Setr::operator+ (Setr &s)
            {
                Setr summ;
                int i = 0;
                summ.ptr[0] = ptr[i];
                for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
                {
                    summ += ptr[i];
                    summ.getSetr();
                }
                i = 0;
                bool f = false;
                for (i = 0; i < s.size; i++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                    {
                        if (s.ptr[i] == ptr[k])
                        {
                            f = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (f == true)
                    {
                        f = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                        summ += s.ptr[i];
                    summ.getSetr();
                }
                return summ;
            }

Setr::Setr()
{
    size = 1;
    ptr = new int[size];
    ptr[0] = 0;
}

Setr::Setr(int Setrsize)
{
    size = Setrsize;
    ptr = new int[Setrsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < Setrsize; i++)
        ptr[i] = 0;
}

Setr::Setr(const Setr &SetrToCopy)
    :size(SetrToCopy.size)
{
    ptr = new int[SetrToCopy.size];

    for (int i = 0; i < SetrToCopy.size; i++)
        ptr[i] = SetrToCopy.ptr[i];
}
Метод суммы не возвращает значение массива
```

Comment: Метод возвращает битую ссылку на локальную переменную, которая вышла из области видимости.

Comment: Как это пофиксить?

Comment: Возвращать не ссылку, а значение.

Comment: У меня объект класса- указатель, я не очень понимаю, как это сделать.

Comment: У вас объект класса - это объект класса. У функции надо только поменять тип возвращаемого значения вместо ссылки возвращать просто новый объект.

Comment: Всё равно не помогло

Comment: Что значит "не помогло"? Теперь метод корректно возвращает объект. Если что-то еще идет не так, то следует приводить конкретный пример использования и чем он не устраивает.

Answer (score 0):

```
Setr &Setr::operator+ (Setr &s)
{
    Setr summ;
    return summ;
}
```

У Вас в коде функция возвращает ссылку `Setr &`.

Ссылка возвращается на объект `Setr summ;`, который существует только внутри функции (а возвращается вы во вне), поэтому принимающая сторона получает ссылку на уже несуществующий объект (функция же закончила выполняться, все внутрифункционные объекты перестали существовать)

Поэтому для исправления ошибки просто возвращайте само значение:

```
Setr Setr::operator+ (Setr &s)
{
    Setr summ;
    return summ;
}
```

Произойдёт копирование Setr summ и всё будет в порядке.

P.S.

есть более извратный вариант - возвращать указатель

```
Setr* Setr::operator+ (Setr &s)
{
    Setr* summ = new Setr;
    return summ;
}
```

правда во-первых надо будет его самому потом удалять, а во-вторых вряд ли Вам нужны такие сложности (где-то такой код уместен, но избыточен для Вашего примера).

Comment: Переделал- всё равно не работает

Comment: вы создаёте Setr summ - как выглядит конструктор? Вы же сразу начинаете пихать значения в ::ptr - Он инициализирован?

Comment: Прикрепил, конструкторы, но, вроде, все инициализируют значения